# How can I use ActivePerl's PPM 4 from the command line?

Tags: perl

The version of PPM (4.06, and I run it under Windows) directly puts me into a GUI which is a nice but since I'm quite comfortable with the command-line prompt so I still want to find a way to get a command-line prompt instead of a GUI.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you call ppm without arguments or as `ppm gui`, then it will be used the GUI. If you use other parameters, then the GUI will not be used.

The list of the arguments accepted by the command includes

```
ppm install [--area <area>] [--force] <pkg>
ppm install [--area <area>] [--force] <module>
ppm install [--area <area>] <url>
ppm upgrade [--install]
ppm upgrade <pkg>
ppm upgrade <module>
ppm remove [--area <area>] [--force] <pkg>
ppm area list [--csv] [--no-header]
ppm area sync
ppm list [--fields <fieldnames>] [--csv]
ppm list <area> [--fields <fieldnames>] [--csv]
ppm files <pkg>
ppm verify [<pkg>]
```

You can find the complete list at [ActivePerl](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/bin/ppm.html).

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the command line prompt interface has been removed; last I knew (quite some time ago), ActivePerl was still including multiple versions of the ppm tool, so `ppm3` might work for you.